# Gradle Sync taking a lot of time

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle SYNC is taking more than 3hrs. The code seems to be Syncing forever (i have tried rebooting Android Studio but it does not help), I am observing this after updating Gradle and Android studio yesterday. It is stuck in Gradle Sync Condfigure build and taking forever to complete and finish

I have tried following tricks and techniques:

```
1) Updated Android Studio to 3.5
2) Tried File-->Settings-->Gradle-->Offline Work
3) Internet connection superfast
4) Not behind any Proxy or VPN
```

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//***********************************************************************************************//
def IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING_ENV_VAR_NAME = project.hasProperty('DeviceConnectionString') ? '"'+project.property('DeviceConnectionString')+'"' : '"Define Device Connection"'
def STRING='String'
//***********************************************************************************************//

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iothub.azure.microsoft.com.androidsample"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        each {
            //buildTypes.mBuildConfigFields 'DATATYPE','VARIABLE',|"GRADLE VARIABLE|"'
            buildConfigField STRING, 'DeviceConnectionString', IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING_ENV_VAR_NAME
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA"
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'thirdpartynotice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation ('com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.14.2'){
        exclude module: 'azure-storage'
    }
    implementation ('com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0@aar')
    implementation ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

[image: Android Studio Gradle Sync ongoing for last 3 hrs]

Comment: Which is your gradle version? Update gradle and rebuild your project.

Comment: Also had the same issue, but my build was up and running for more than a day. After I cleaned project and restarted workstation (also were using Windows), it built properly. I've also tried pretty much everything I could find on sof, but if possible restart your machine then try again.

Comment: It is Gradle error. After updating it takes too much time and in Release build it goes in error. So the solution updates all things like androidx after that it won't come or decrease your Gradle version.

Comment: This seems to be culprit: My Antivirus seems to be creating some trouble probably, this is however corporate Laptop and I do not have access to AntiVirus settings What should I do now ?

Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories: 
    D:\Android\SDK
    C:\Users\abdhar\.gradle
    C:\Users\abdhar\.AndroidStudio3.5\system
    D:\Users\abdhar\Downloads\azure-iot-samples-java-master\iot-hub\Samples\device\AndroidSample
    Don't show again
    Don't show again for this project
    Details